# How to find last commit on a branch prior to a given merge commit

Tags: git

I have a branch, develop, to which I merged several days ago using commit hash *92dd09b*.

For clarity, here is an image of my commit in Git Extensions:
[image]

Given that hash, I need to find the prior commit on the develop branch prior to my merge.  How would I go about doing that?

If I check out my commit hash, git log shows the previous commits on my branch, not on develop.

I looked at this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41628914/how-to-find-last-git-commit-before-a-merge), then I checked out my merge hash (*92dd09b*) and ran this command:
git log HEAD@{1} -1

But I get an error:
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD@': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

I'm using Git for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, it seems as though I misread your question regarding what commit `92dd09b` identifies.  I've kept my original answer below to avoid making the comment conversations even more confusing.  But based on my current understanding, you really have

```
                              ... x
                                   \
x -- x -- x -- A -- 92dd09b -- x -- M2 -- x <--(develop)
                   /
         ... x -- B <--(branch)
```

In that case, what you tried first (checkout `92dd09b`, run git log) should show the commits from both branches; you could exclude the commits from the "merged in" branch by saying

```
git log --first-parent
```

Or, per phd's answer, you could say

```
git show 92dd09b~
```

(among other things).

Your comments indicate that this didn't get you to the right commit, though, which suggests that something is incorrectly observed.

---

So as I understand the question you had a develop branch

```
x -- x -- x -- A <--(develop)
```

and you had another branch

```
x -- x -- x -- A <--(develop)

   ... x -- 92dd09b <--(branch)
```

and you merged `92dd09b` into `develop`

```
x -- x -- x -- A -- M1 <--(develop)
                   /
   ... x -- 92dd09b <--(branch)
```

and now maybe some more work has happened

```
                        ... x
                             \
x -- x -- x -- A -- M1 -- x -- M2 -- x <--(develop)
                   /
   ... x -- 92dd09b <--(branch)
```

So now you want to find `A`.

As a rule, commits make it easy to look "back in time"; less easy to look forward.  If you start from `92dd09b`, you have to "look forward" to get to `M1`, and *then* look back at `A`.

So it's not as easy as you might hope.  But it can be done.  You could start with

```
git log --merges --format=%p develop
```

This will give you parent lists for each merge commit in `develop`, one on each line.  So then you can filter that in any number of ways.

```
git log --merges --format=%p develop |grep 92dd09b$ |cut -d" " -f1
```

should print the abbreviated hash of the "other" parent of `M1`, which should be `A`.  (Assuming it's not an octopus merge, and assuming you merged 92dd09b *into* `develop` and not the other way around.)

Comment: This is close.  My commit WAS the merge commit.  It would be M1, I think.  I have added an image of my commit in GitExtensions for reference, just in case I am not describing it properly.

Comment: @EricBurcham : Well, now that is confusing.  If you're saying that 92dd09b is the merge commit, then phd's answer should've returned the correct result.

Comment: @EricBurcham - And for that matter, `git log` would then show commits on *both* branches.  You could refine that as `git log --first-parent` to exclude the other branch, and see *only* the commits from `develop`

Comment: OK, looking very carefully at the result, the result from git show 92dd09b~ return the correct commit.  That commit was merged both into my branch, AND is the most recent commit on develop prior to my merge.  It was merged separately before my merge.  Go figure.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to checkout the merge so let's return back to develop:

```
git checkout develop
```

To get the previous commit from the known hash:

```
git show 92dd09b~
```

There are many different ways to navigate through history naming one commit from the other: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions

Comment: Well, if @EricBurcham says that's perfect, then ok; but I'm guessing he hasn't tested it when he says that, because if `92dd09b` is the commit merged in, then `92dd09b~` is a commit from his other branch - same as with the procedure he used.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger you are correct.  It returned a different hash, so I assumed it was right.  When I looked at the git log, I did not notice the fact that this commit is ALSO in my branch.

Can you suggest the correct thing to do?

Comment: @EricBurcham - Posted as an answer