# Returning to "initial commit" yields incomplete files

Tags: git

I attempted to merge 2 projects. Project_old and project_new. One which is ahead by a year into one which is behind. I put the projects into separate folders and did this in both of them:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

I didn't make any backups of project_old, because I expected git to have it all in the repo in it's old state.

I then added a remote branch to project_old:

```
git remote add project_newer /path/to/project_new
git fetch project_newer
```

I then began to merge them both

```
git merge project_newer/master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

It produced some merge conflicts, so I fixed them with mergetool.

However, something went wrong with the merge and I ended up overwriting some important files from project_old with that of project_new, or so it seemed.

So I thought ok I will make a copy of project_old in it's failed merged state and do the checkout to initial commit's hash and do the merge again:

```
git checkout XXXXXX
```

But, for some reason, this commit only includes 10% of project_old which makes no sense whatsoever. I check the log with `git log --stat` and I can see that only this 10% is included in the first commit. The next commit in the list is the "Initial commit" of project_new's repo, and the 3rd one is the merged final (the current master).

1. Is there a way to return project_old to it's complete state it was in at the time of it's first commit?
2. What went wrong so I can learn to not do this in future?

Answer (score 0):

Check [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) or [simply git log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41628915/6309): it should have the commit it was before the merge.

Try and checkout that commit, instead of the initial one.

Comment: I get the following with `git reflog`:

    `4717fec (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to master
    4717fec (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{1}: commit (merge): Merge 1
    8ccdef9 HEAD@{2}: commit (initial): Initial commit`

I checkout 8ccdef9 with `git checkout 8ccdef9`, and all I have is 10% of the project and even missing half the folder structure.

Comment: @Kris And what is in  4717fec ?

Comment: it's this: Merge: 8ccdef9 11b1321, the current master.

Comment: So do yo see only three commits with `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all --branches`?

Comment: @Kris what if you checkout/restore 11b1321?

Comment: I did that as well, 11b1321 is the hash of the repo project_newer's "Initial commit". Checking that out produces a copy of project_newer (which is an untouched repo except for it's initial commit).

Comment: So no commits from logs or reflog includes the full content of your repo?

Comment: That is exactly right, and I confirmed it by doing `git log --stat` to view the list of files in the commit 8ccdef9 and it lists only the partial content.

Comment: @Kris So... it is like a (big) part of that project was never added/commit, then.

Comment: Yes indeed, but how is that possible if I did a `git add .` before the initial commit to the empty repo? I checked my `.bash_history` multiple times to confirm the order of what I did and I did this in the same order for both of those projects folders

Comment: @Kris possibly part of it was ignored: `git check-ignore -v -- a/file/which/should/have been/added`.

Comment: Using check ignore for a file that should be there produced no output. I just copied the relevent part out of my `.bash_history`: https://pastebin.com/raw/GX9nZg7x. In that example PROJECT OLD CONTENTS was a working project in the current home directory, so it's physically not possible for it to be incomplete...

Comment: @Kris So you don't have the full content of the old project anywhere? (I mean, outside Git)

Comment: I do, I am just curious what went wrong and how this happened.

Comment: @Kris I would try again to add and commit the full content in a new repository, and redo the mer e, to see if you get the same result.